# Way to display byte ptr watch in OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, assembly, ollydbg

Is there a way to display a byte pointer as a watch in OllyDbg?

For example, if you enter as a watch an expression like [ecx+ebx] you might get a value like "FF084001", but if you want the byte pointer, the least significant byte (which is 01 here) there seems to be no way to display just that one byte. I tried entering:

byte ptr [ecx+ebx]

and got the error "Unrecognized identifier".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `[BYTE ecx+ebx]`. Found in the documentation (`help.pdf`) by keyword  `expression`.